# pytest unit test for "logging+multi-process+QueueHandler"

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, queue, pytest

## Question

I don't know how to write the unit test for [the codes below](https://github.com/changchiyou/haplog/blob/2c84dc843cc57587c7525fb2e6fe74c6d06c7775/haplog/logger_utils.py#L1-L191):

```py
"""Some implements of `logging` enhancement."""
import logging
import multiprocessing
import platform
import queue
from logging import handlers
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable

LOGGING_FORMAT = (
    "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] %(filename)s - %(funcName)s() : %(message)s"
)
BASE_LOG_NAME = "record"
SUFFIX_LOG_NAME = "%Y-%m-%d.log"


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Custom log formatter class that inherits from `logging.Formatter`.
    It formats the log messages based on their log levels and applies color settings.
    """

    def __init__(self, costom_format: str):
        super().__init__()

        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            from colorama import init  # type: ignore

            init()

        # https://talyian.github.io/ansicolors/

        # black = "\x1b[30;20m"
        red = "\x1b[31;20m"
        bold_red = "\x1b[31;1m"
        green = "\x1b[32;20m"
        yellow = "\x1b[33;20m"
        # blue = "\x1b[34;20m"
        # magenta = "\x1b[35;20m"
        # cyan = "\x1b[36;20m"
        # white = "\x1b[37;20m"
        grey = "\x1b[38;20m"

        # \x1b[38;2;r;g;bm - foreground
        # \x1b[48;2;r;g;bm - background

        reset = "\x1b[0m"

        self.formats = {
            logging.DEBUG: grey + costom_format + reset,
            logging.INFO: green + costom_format + reset,
            logging.WARNING: yellow + costom_format + reset,
            logging.ERROR: red + costom_format + reset,
            logging.CRITICAL: bold_red + costom_format + reset,
        }

    def format(self, record):
        log_fmt = self.formats.get(record.levelno)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_fmt)
        return formatter.format(record)


class OutputLogger:
    """
    serves as a pseudo file-like stream object that redirects written content to a logger instance.
    It overrides the `write` method to append the written messages to an internal buffer
    (`linebuf`). When a message ends with a newline character, it logs the buffered messages
    as a log record.
    """

    def __init__(self, logger_name: str, logging_level: int = logging.INFO) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        self.logging_level = logging_level
        self.linebuf = ""

    def write(self, msg: str) -> None:
        r"""
        If redirected output end without `\n`, append it into `self.linebuf`,
        and log it out when the redirected output which end with `\n` comes.
        """
        self.linebuf += msg
        if msg.endswith("\n") is True:
            self.logger.log(
                self.logging_level,
                self.linebuf.rstrip(),
                stack_info=False,
                stacklevel=2,
            )
            self.linebuf = ""

    def flush(self) -> None:
        """
        Note that self.linebuf = '' is where the flush is being handled,
        rather than implementing a flush function.
        """


class MultiProcessLogger:
    """
    Implements a custom logger designed for multi-process environments.
    It is based on the 'Logging Cookbook - Logging to a single file from multiple processes' example
    in the Python documentation. It utilizes a multiprocessing queue and a listener process to
    enable logging across multiple processes. The class provides functionality for logging records
    to a file and printing logs to the console.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        # record logs into file
        log_path: str | Path | None = None,
        level_log: int = logging.DEBUG,
        format_log: str = LOGGING_FORMAT,
        base_log_name: str = BASE_LOG_NAME,
        suffix_log_name: str = SUFFIX_LOG_NAME,
        rotate_period: tuple[str, int] = ("midnight", 1),
        # print logs on console
        level_console: int = logging.INFO,
        format_console: str = LOGGING_FORMAT,
    ):
        self.log_path = log_path
        self.level_log = level_log
        self.format_log = format_log
        self.base_log_name = base_log_name
        self.suffix_log_name = suffix_log_name
        self.rotate_period = rotate_period
        self.level_console = level_console
        self.format_console = format_console

        self.queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(-1)
        self.listener = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=self.listener_process, args=(self.queue, self.listener_configurer)
        )

    def listener_configurer(self):
        root = logging.getLogger()

        # logger for logs
        if self.log_path is not None:
            formatter_log = logging.Formatter(self.format_log)
            handler_log = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
                (Path(self.log_path) / self.base_log_name).resolve(),
                when=self.rotate_period[0],
                interval=self.rotate_period[1],
                encoding="utf-8",
            )
            handler_log.setFormatter(formatter_log)
            handler_log.suffix = self.suffix_log_name
            root.addHandler(handler_log)

        # logger for console
        handler_console = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler_console.setLevel(self.level_console)
        handler_console.setFormatter(CustomFormatter(self.format_console))
        root.addHandler(handler_console)

    def listener_process(self, _queue: queue.Queue, configurer: Callable) -> None:
        configurer()
        while True:
            try:
                record = _queue.get()
                if record is None:
                    break
                logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
                logger.handle(record)
            except Exception:
                import sys
                import traceback

                print(
                    "Oops! An issue occurred during the logging process:",
                    file=sys.stderr,
                )
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

    def start(self):
        self.listener.start()

    def join(self):
        self.queue.put_nowait(None)
        self.listener.join()


def worker_configurer(_queue: queue.Queue, worker_level: int = logging.DEBUG) -> None:
    """
    Configure the logger for worker processes with input `_queue` handler.
    """
    handler = handlers.QueueHandler(_queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(handler)
    # send all messages
    root.setLevel(worker_level)
```

## Introdoction

I want to develop a small project about configuring `logging`. I have completed most of it on [haplog](https://github.com/changchiyou/haplog)(my own repo). However, I realized that`haplog` did not support multi-process, so I referred to [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) and implemented it.

I was able to confirm that it works perfectly when installing `haplog` via executing:

```
pip install "https://github.com/changchiyou/haplog/archive/main/v1.0.2.zip"
```

And running [the demo code](https://github.com/changchiyou/haplog/blob/2c84dc843cc57587c7525fb2e6fe74c6d06c7775/examples/demo_haplog.py#L1-L71)

```py
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from pathlib import Path

from haplog import MultiProcessLogger, OutputLogger, worker_configurer

LOGGER_NAME = "test"
MESSAGE = "test"

log_folder = (Path(__file__).parent) / "logs"

if log_folder.exists() is False:
    log_folder.mkdir()


def third_party_function():
    print(MESSAGE + " by third_party_function()")


def single_process():
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(log_folder, level_console=logging.DEBUG)
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    with redirect_stdout(
        OutputLogger(logger_name=LOGGER_NAME, logging_level=logging.DEBUG)  # type: ignore
    ):
        print(MESSAGE + " by print()")
        third_party_function()

    logger.debug(MESSAGE)
    logger.info(MESSAGE)
    logger.warning(MESSAGE)
    logger.error(MESSAGE)
    logger.critical(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()


def worker_process(queue, configurer):
    import time
    from random import random

    configurer(queue)

    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.info("Worker started: %s" % name)
    time.sleep(random())
    logger.info("Worker finished: %s" % name)


def multi_process():
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(log_folder, level_console=logging.DEBUG)
    mpl.start()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for _ in range(10):
            executor.submit(worker_process, mpl.queue, worker_configurer)

    mpl.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    single_process()
    multi_process()
```

I got the result

```
2023-06-16 12:11:01,919 DEBUG    [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test by print()
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 DEBUG    [test] demo_haplog.py - third_party_function() : test by third_party_function()
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 DEBUG    [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 INFO     [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 WARNING  [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 ERROR    [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test
2023-06-16 12:11:01,920 CRITICAL [test] demo_haplog.py - single_process() : test
2023-06-16 12:11:02,222 INFO     [SpawnProcess-5] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-5
2023-06-16 12:11:02,229 INFO     [SpawnProcess-7] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-7
2023-06-16 12:11:02,230 INFO     [SpawnProcess-6] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-6
2023-06-16 12:11:02,243 INFO     [SpawnProcess-8] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-8
2023-06-16 12:11:02,246 INFO     [SpawnProcess-9] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-9
2023-06-16 12:11:02,253 INFO     [SpawnProcess-10] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-10
2023-06-16 12:11:02,276 INFO     [SpawnProcess-11] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-11
2023-06-16 12:11:02,287 INFO     [SpawnProcess-12] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-12
2023-06-16 12:11:02,304 INFO     [SpawnProcess-13] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-13
2023-06-16 12:11:02,316 INFO     [SpawnProcess-14] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker started: SpawnProcess-14
2023-06-16 12:11:02,538 INFO     [SpawnProcess-7] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-7
2023-06-16 12:11:02,562 INFO     [SpawnProcess-11] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-11
2023-06-16 12:11:02,634 INFO     [SpawnProcess-6] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-6
2023-06-16 12:11:02,665 INFO     [SpawnProcess-5] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-5
2023-06-16 12:11:02,787 INFO     [SpawnProcess-14] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-14
2023-06-16 12:11:02,791 INFO     [SpawnProcess-13] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-13
2023-06-16 12:11:02,962 INFO     [SpawnProcess-9] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-9
2023-06-16 12:11:03,047 INFO     [SpawnProcess-12] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-12
2023-06-16 12:11:03,184 INFO     [SpawnProcess-10] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-10
2023-06-16 12:11:03,243 INFO     [SpawnProcess-8] demo_haplog.py - worker_process() : Worker finished: SpawnProcess-8
```

As evidenced by this screenshot: [result.imgur](https://i.imgur.com/jQgP93Y.png) (I know [@Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) said "Links to code or images of text can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.", but my project includes the feature about coloring text, so I guess that I have to provide the VFX)

---

## What have I tried

However, I don't know how to update my unit test. Before (updated the feature about supporting multi-process), I could easily check the output via `pytest.capsys`:

```py
def test_console_info(capsys):
    instantiate_logger(LOGGER_NAME)
    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    captured = capsys.readouterr()

    assert f'INFO     {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_info() : {MESSAGE}' in captured.err
```

But after I updated it, seems `capsys` has no ability to catch the log from other process:

```py
def test_console_info(capsys):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger()
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    captured = capsys.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"INFO     {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_info() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )
```

```
E       AssertionError: assert 'INFO     test_instantiate_logger.py - test_console_info() : test' in ''
E        +  where '' = CaptureResult(out='', err='').err
```

I have also tried `caplog` and `capfd`, but none of them works for me.

Due to the fact that `haplog` now uses `Queue` and `QueueHandler` to send all logging events to one of the processes so that it can handle multiple processes, I don't know how to read/check the entire logs from another process using `pytest`.

Comment: Please post the *relevant* code and the output as text in the question itself. Links to code or images of text can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KlausD. already updated, thanks for your notification, it's my first time asking question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have also tried caplog and capfd, but none of them works for me.

I found that `capfd` actually works for me, it failed because I forget execute `mpl.join()`(close the log-listener process) before.

```
=========================================================== test session starts ============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.11, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/christopherchang/Code/logger_utils
collected 6 items                                                                                                                          

tests/test_instantiate_logger.py ......                                                                                              [100%]

============================================================ 6 passed in 1.94s =============================================================
```

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path

from haplog import BASE_LOG_NAME, MultiProcessLogger, worker_configurer

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76487303/pytest-unit-test-for-loggingmulti-processqueuehandler
# May be useful: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3037#issuecomment-745050393

LOGGER_NAME = "test"
MESSAGE = "test"


def test_console_default_info(capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger()
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    captured = capfd.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_default_info() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )


def test_console_unused_config_path(tmp_path, capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(tmp_path)
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    captured = capfd.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_unused_config_path() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )


def test_console_info(capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(level_console=logging.INFO)
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    captured = capfd.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_info() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )


def test_console_debug(capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(level_console=logging.DEBUG)
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.debug(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    captured = capfd.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"DEBUG    [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_debug() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )


def test_console_debug_info_level(capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger()
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.debug(MESSAGE)
    logger.info(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    captured = capfd.readouterr()

    assert (
        f"DEBUG    [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_debug_info_level() : {MESSAGE}"
        not in captured.err
    )
    assert (
        f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_console_debug_info_level() : {MESSAGE}"
        in captured.err
    )


def test_log(tmp_path, capfd):
    mpl = MultiProcessLogger(log_path=tmp_path, level_console=logging.DEBUG)
    mpl.start()
    worker_configurer(mpl.queue)

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

    logger.info(MESSAGE)
    logger.debug(MESSAGE)

    mpl.join()

    with open(tmp_path / BASE_LOG_NAME, mode="r") as File:
        contents = File.read()
        File.close()

        captured = capfd.readouterr()

        assert (
            f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_log() : {MESSAGE}"
            in captured.err
        )

        assert (
            f"INFO     [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_log() : {MESSAGE}"
            in contents
        )
        assert (
            f"DEBUG    [{LOGGER_NAME}] {Path(__file__).name} - test_log() : {MESSAGE}"
            in contents
        )
```